# How do I disable update checks for locked projects?

Tags: drush, updating, cron

I am using `drush @sites cron` in order to get update notifications in a Drupal 7 multisite configuration.
However, I need to have some projects locked, using `drush up --lock=context_mobile_detect`.

Example:

```
.var.vhosts.drupalmulti#example.com           >>  Name                     Installed Version  Proposed version  Message
.var.vhosts.drupalmulti#example.com           >>  Context Mobile Detect    7.x-1.3            7.x-2.0-alpha1    **Locked via drush.**
.var.vhosts.drupalmulti#example.com           >>  (context_mobile_detect)                                       (Installed version not
.var.vhosts.drupalmulti#example.com           >>                                                                supported)
```

Since this command checks many sites, it sends many unnecessary emails of the form: "New release(s) available for example.com", although most of the time no module needs to be updated.

Is there a way, using code or not, to disable update checking of locked projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`drush cron` will trigger the default update manager search, whereas locked project are only locked during `drush pm-updatestatus`. If you want to prevent Update Manager from checking for particular modules, you'll need a custom module that implements [`hook_update_projects_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21update%21update.api.php/function/hook_update_projects_alter/7.x). All you have to do then is `unset($projects['context_mobile_detect']);`.

E.g.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_update_projects_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_update_projects_alter(&$projects) {
  unset($projects['context_mobile_detect']);
}
```

I do this quite a lot for Features modules, or custom code.

Comment: +1. That is the code suggested for modules not hosted on drupal.org, such as custom modules, but it does its job also for modules you don't want to update for any reason.